# Logical error with Lists with two lists giving the same value

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm calculating the values based on two panda dfs, and storing in two lists. But when I see the output, it's storing the same (latter) value in both the lists. I'm unclear what I'm missing here. The logic works in R. Also, while calculating, it has different values - but then gets "forced" into the same value.

```
for i in range(10):
    x[i] = (trt.loc[i, "Average Cost"] - ctrl.loc[i, "Average Cost"] + int_cost)
    print(x[i])
    y[i] = (ctrl.loc[i, "Average DALYs"] - trt.loc[i, "Average DALYs"]) * 100 / ctrl.loc[i, "Average DALYs"]
    print(x[i],y[i])
```

The print was for trouble shooting, and it shows the issue:

Output shows up as:

```
x[0] -> 5.49694781325778
x[0], y[0] -> 4.087583849991359 4.087583849991359
x[1] -> 0.558115134887974
x[1], y[1] -> 3.454047352322206 3.454047352322206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` and `y` seem to be referencing the same list. Possibly you've done something similar to

```
>>> x, y = ([],)*2
```

You can check if this is the case by doing:

```
>>> x is y
True
```

Fix this by making sure to initiate x and y with different list objects, for example:

```
>>> x, y = ([], [])
>>> x is y
False
```

Comment: Yes. I was doing that. Thank a lot. Didn't know something that elementary will be the issue.:( I had initiated them as x = y = [0.00 for  i in range(samples)]